# Convert convex Geometry to concave Geomerty in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using THREE.js 64 version. Now i am working to create mesh from vertices using convex geometry in three.js. My problem is convex geometry creates closed surface. I need any idea to create non-convex or concave geometry in three.js

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use geometry with holes. As with this example which is not really a convex geometry. 
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have the shape you can compute the average length of the mesh faces and delete the longest faces. A harder solution is to use alpha shapes. You can look at my website:http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence. When you have the shape you can use a constrained mesh algorithm.